# MongoDB .NET Driver Mapping values as null

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB Driver to try and map BsonDocument to a model. When I try to read models from a collection, string values are null, DateTimes are the minimum value, and enums are their default value. Here is a document I'd like to read from a collection:

[image]

This is the class I'd like to map it to:

```
public class PhotoModel
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(PhotoCategorySerializer))]
    public PhotoCategory Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Here is where I define the mapping:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<PhotoModel>(cm =>
        {
            cm.MapMember(c => c.Id);
            cm.MapMember(c => c.Name);
            cm.MapMember(c => c.Description);
            cm.MapMember(c => c.Category);
            cm.MapMember(c => c.UserID);
            cm.MapMember(c => c.Created);
        });
```

I use `MapMember` instead of `AutoMap` because I don't want `file` to be a part of my model.
This is the code where I try to read from the collection:

```
public class PhotoRepository : IPhotoRepository
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<PhotoModel> photos;

    public PhotoRepository(IMongoClient mongoClient)
    {
        photos = mongoClient.GetDatabase("photo-share").GetCollection<PhotoModel>("photos");
    }

    public IEnumerable<PhotoModel> GetAllPhotos() => photos.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
}
```

This is what I see when I debug `photos.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList()`:
[image]

Why is the class not mapped properly?

Also, a related question: where should I perform the mappings? The docs said to register class maps before initializing a MongoDB connection, so I do it in Program.cs before the host is built and run. Is that a good place for it?

Comment: Maybe, the the field names of MongoDB collection document and the class property names need to be of the same case (right now it is `name` and `Name` respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this. you don't even need to specify mapping. mongo driver takes care of that. your main problem is the mismatched casing of db field names and class property names.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class PhotoModel
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("category"), BsonSerializer(typeof(PhotoCategorySerializer))]
        public PhotoCategory Category { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("userID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("created")]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static readonly IMongoClient client = 
            new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");

        private static readonly IMongoCollection<PhotoModel> photoCollection =
            client.GetDatabase("photo-share").GetCollection<PhotoModel>("photos");

        private static async Task Main()
        {
            IEnumerable<PhotoModel> photos = await photoCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

you could even eliminate the need for the attribute decorations by registering a convension pack like so:

```cs
ConventionRegistry.Register(
    "MyConvensions",
    new ConventionPack
    {
        new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true),
        new CamelCaseElementNameConvention()
    },
    _ => true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked! I have a question about the convention pack though. Where should this registration be performed? I'm guessing `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`.

Comment: @AnthonyBias starup.cs should be ok. basically anywhere before the mongo client is created i believe.